# Missing "New Haxe Project" in FDT Free

Tags: eclipse, haxe, fdt

I've just downloaded the FDT IDE Free version from its [website](http://fdt.powerflasher.com/buy-download/). I wanted to use it for Haxe development so at first startup I chose to develop Haxe projects only. However in the "New FDT Project" window I cannot find the Haxe project templates:
[image: No Haxe projects here]
I added the Haxe and Neko paths in the preferences but it didn't solved it. I also tried to add them in the "Installed SDKs" tab but I got an error stating that it couldn't find SDKs in that given folder. My last desperate try was to extract a new FDT application and set it that I want to develop AS and Flex applications too but no luck. I still cannot create Haxe projects.
However what is wierd that the version of FDT is around 1.x.x.x:
[image: Low version number]
But as far as I know the latest version is 5.5. Does the free version have separate versioning or I managed to download an outdated version? If the last is true then I don't really know where could I get the latest release since as mentioned above, I downloaded it from the official site.

---

The same goes for using FDT as a plug-in in an Eclipse Juno installation. Haxe projects are missing there too.

---

Checked the AppData folder of FDT, and there are Haxe project templates but no Haxe project type:
[image: projectTemplate2 folder]
[image: projectType2 folder]

---

I originally downloaded the win64 version, but already tried the win32 version and still no Haxe project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chatted with tech support at FDT.  Apparently, minor bug in the project template configuration files that will be fixed with an upcoming release.

Unsure where they are on non OSX platforms, but for the mac, they are in:
~/Library/Application Support/FDT/projectTemplates2/haxe/*/description.xml

Edit the files and change the 'version' tag from 2.7 to 2.8.  Then relaunch FDT and the Haxe project templates will display.

Comment: On Windows the above path is: c:\Users\your_username\AppData\Roaming\FDT\projectTemplates2\Haxe\